# How to read xml data within csv file using pyspark

Tags: python-3.x, pyspark, databricks

There is text,xml data in csv file. How to read the xml data and create data frame using pyspark in databrics.

```
Hotel Id,Hotel Name,Food
1,GoodHotel,<food>
    <item name="breakfast">Idly</item>
    <price>$2.5</price>
    <description>
   Two idly's with chutney
   </description>
    <calories>553</calories>
</food>
```

---

need to extract data all in columnar format.

1,GoodHotel,breakfast,2.5 etc

Answer (score 0):

It's could be done by using [spark-xml library](https://github.com/databricks/spark-xml/) from Databricks.  The [documentation](https://github.com/databricks/spark-xml/#parsing-nested-xml) covers how to use `from_xml` function for that, and it's possible to do that from [PySpark](https://github.com/databricks/spark-xml/#pyspark-notes) as well (don't copy the code here as it may change).

If you need only a single attribute, alternative approach would be to use SQL functions like `xpath` ([doc](https://docs.databricks.com/sql/language-manual/sql-ref-functions-builtin.html#xpath-functions)) called from `.selectExpr` or `expr`, something like this (assuming that CSV is already parsed):

```py
from pyspark.sql.functions import expr

df = df.withColumn("food_type", "xpath_string(food,'item@name');"
```